# Ember.js Observer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observers

I want to use observer on a variable which is in service, that's my code:

```
const get = Ember.get;

uploader:Ember.inject.service('uploader'),

progressChanged: Ember.observer(this.get('uploader').get('progress'), function() {
  console.log('observer is called', this.get('uploader').get('progress'));
}),
```

That's the error:

> Error while processing route: index this.get is not a function

When I'm trying to show the progress in alert:

```
actions:
    {
        getProgress()
        {
            alert("progress:"+this.get('uploader').get('progress'));
        }
    }
```

Everything works, but not in an observer. What should I do?

Comment: `Ember.observer('uploader.progress', ...`

Comment: It worked ! Thank You !

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `Ember.observer`?

Comment: I need to read it more precisely :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` context is not valid one. Like Kitler suggested, The below should solve your problem.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    uploader:Ember.inject.service(),//if service name is uploader
    progressChanged: Ember.observer('uploader.progress',function() {
        console.log('observer is called', this.get('uploader').get('progress'));
    }),
});
```

I would suggest not to overuse observer, you can try using computed property. If you just want to show progress alone then you dont need observer, you can simply use  `this.get('uploader.progress')` or through `Ember.computed.alias('uploader.progress')`.

Reference: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/object-model/observers/